# How to scale a kubernetes deployment on GKE without using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

This may seem like a bit of an oddity, but I need to scale a kubernetes deployment that I have running on GKE, but where I'm initiating the call, I do not have access to kubectl.

So we have a VM that is running airflow (airflow is a tool we use for building automated data ETL pipelines).  The team responsible for it don't want to give the VM access to GKE directly, and don't want kubectl installed on it.  So I'm trying to think of a way around this limitation.

My current thinking is to use pub/sub and have airflow publish a notification that it wants the deployment to scale, but I'm not really sure what I need on the subscribe end to actually handle that?  I've been looking into the operator SDK, and that's looking promising, but it's got me wondering do I need to go to the effort of building a custom operator and setting everything up, or is there something that already exists that I could use?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you **can** access? Sounds like they don't want any direct access from the airflow VM to the GKE cluster. From where **can** you access the cluster (programmatically). Doesn't matter how many layers of indirection and intermediate APIs you build between airflow VM and the cluster if you have no point of access to the cluster at all. Probably best to have this conversation with the team responsible for the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current thinking is to use pub/sub and have airflow publish a notification that it wants the deployment to scale, but I'm not really sure what I need on the subscribe end to actually handle that?

I imagine you could [trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) on a Pub/Sub message and then in the Cloud Function use something like the [Kubernetes python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to scale your cluster.

A bit of a different approach would be to have your Airflow VM [publish a custom metric to Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) and then use that [custom metric to configure autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/external-metrics-autoscaling).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deploying `bastion host` would be a good solution in your case.
You can read about details of such approach in this [article](https://medium.com/@rajtmana/securing-your-kubernetes-cluster-in-google-cloud-platform-cbad59f62ce3).

> Bastion host provides an entry point of a K8S cluster (in this
>   context) and gives other resource management capabilities. Typically
>   this is a Google Compute Engine VM created in the same VPC and subnet.
>   ... Since this VM is in the same VPC and the subnet IP range is
>   whitelisted in the master access list of the K8S cluster, this VM can
>   be used to manage the cluster. So this VM should have the Google Cloud
>   SDK installed and the required tools such as kubectl.

Answer (score -1):

Provided you have access(authentication credentials) to the kubernetes cluster, you can call the kubernetes api server with credentials and create horizontal pod autoscaling. You can also use [python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AutoscalingV1Api.md#create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler) sdk to do the same.

Comment: This is what I'm saying.  I don't have access to the kubernetes cluster.  The team who own airflow here don't want it to have that level of access, which is why I'm trying to build a more specific API that it can access, to minimize risk.

Comment: If you don't have authentication credentials then you can't access the cluster from anywhere

Comment: No what I'm saying is; I could have another service, be it a VM, a kubernetes pod, an operator, etc, where I could give that access, and then I could change the size of the cluster, but whatever that thing is, could potentially just use kubectl.  What I'm asking is, what is that thing?